# PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

My .env:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=myappkey
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=gestiontaller
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD='root'

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I've tried the password with ", ' and without, restarting server every time. I've also tried changing localhost to 172.0.0.1. Yes, my password is correct, running `mysql -u root -p` introducing my password `root` in the prompt I can go into mysql. My users table:

```
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
| root1            | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

I've also added to my Homestead.yaml this: `database_port: 3306`

Using `php artisan tinker` I'm not having problems with the database creating and adding items, just when trying to acces a view through a controller:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function view ($id){

        $car = Car::find($id);

        $car->category;
        $car->user;
        $car->tags;

        dd($car);
    }
}
```

I've also tried multiple times `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: `-p root` does not mean your password is root. It means to ask you for password if one is required and select the database 'root' (meaning: `-u root`, `-p` and `root` are 3 arguments for the mysql binary, not 2). You're most likely connecting without a password.

Comment: I've just added the root after -p just to clarify that my password is root.

Comment: are you running that command from inside you homestead VM? The database server in your VM is different from the one in your 'real' machine. Depending on your version of Laravel / Homestead, but I believe defaults are `DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret` and defenitely no quotes in your .env file

Comment: No, I'm running it outside. Migrations worked flawlessly as well tinker. All the data is dumped into my 'real' machine database.

Comment: Strange, I would think that migrations use the exact same database connection (provided you call artisan from inside your VM, as you should). I guess it is a host / port forwarding issue, and not so much a authentication issue if you are planning to use the database on your 'real' machine

Comment: Yes they do, as I say migrations are working as intended (my localhost database)

Comment: Again, that is probably because you are running the migrations from **outside** your VM. I strongly suggest to do all artisan / tinker work from **inside** your VM (`homestead ssh`), as this is also the environment that will be used for HTTP request. I bet the migrations won't work there... May I ask if there is a reason you are not using the database server inside your VM?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, my migrations working from outside means the same env file should work for my app, as well tinker, I can build objects and relations from hete and use save() to add them to my database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113226/discussion-between-pevara-and-pablo).